# Computer-readable potentiometer

Tags: arduino, computers, potentiometer

I have a device that essentially controlled by a potentiometer and a rotary switch. I would like to keep these (although I would replace them with other components if that helped), but I'd like to be able to read the position of the switch and potentiometer with a computer (or Arduino for example).

Is there a simple way to do this? I thought I could measure the value of the potentiometer's resistance but it's integrated into a circuit.

Any hints on how to go about this?

Comment: If you want to read the pot and/or switch while it's connected to some other unknown circuit, there is no general answer, and it will most likely be difficult at best.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the voltage with one of the Analog inputs of arduino (pay attention that the maximum input is 5V so if your voltage is higher you should reduce using a voltage divider).

Then you can send the readings to the pc using the serial comunication through the usb port.

You will need than a software that reads the data from the USB port, I have done it many times using python, but any programming language or software can be useful.
If you are interested I can send you some code snippets.